# Hyperlinks in people field descriptions don't work?

Tags: 2007

Looks like I might have found another SharePointism.

When putting a URL in the description of a field, it normally gets automatically converted into a clickable hyperlink. For people fields, however, it seems the URL is not automatically converted into a hyperlink.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I might be a bit slow here in the morning, but are you saying you put a URL into a people field? Why would you do that?

Comment: Not in the people field itself... when you are editing the column, you can fill in a Description, which then shows up underneath the field in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution using JavaScript. I used a [replaceURLWithHTMLLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/replace-url-with-html-links-javascript) function and replaced all the hyperlinks in the description.

In case anyone is curious, the description ended up being inside the last SPAN tag inside the cell with all the people field controls.